# Is it correct to initialize state of child component via props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to initialize state of child component from parent one. So I do it by the following way:

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function () {
          return {timer: this.props.timer};
     },
     render () {
          return <div>{this.state.timer}</div>
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function () {
           return {timer: 1000};
     },
     render () {
          return <Timer timer={this.state.timer}>
     }
});
```

Is it correct to initialize state of Timer component this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine to do it like that.

In your case, I assume you will change the value of `timer` inside the component (say, by some user interactions). Because a value on `state` is supposed to be some `instance variable`, whose value may change to reflect the component status. **But be reminded that changing the `state.timer` value will not change the `timer` value outside.**

If you will not change the value of `this.state.timer` inside the component, you can just use it like:

```
render () {
      return <div>{this.props.timer}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:**
>   This isn't really a React-specific tip, as such anti-patterns often occur in code in general; in this case, React simply points them out more clearly.

Using props to generate state in `getInitialState` often leads to `duplication` of `"source of truth"`, i.e. where the real data is. This is because getInitialState is only invoked when the component is first created.

Whenever possible, compute values on-the-fly to ensure that they don't get out of sync later on and cause maintenance trouble.